# CSS button styles to indicate selected/unselected?

Tags: button, css

I'm using CSS to create a set of toggleable buttons.

I'm almost there, but I don't feel I've got the CSS proprerties quite right: http://jsfiddle.net/rrGab/5/

I think the dark border on the selected button is too dark and too sharply delineated, but I don't know how to make it look smoother.

Could someone suggest how to improve the CSS to make it look better?

I'd love to know the general CSS principles of making buttons "pop" out of the page or appear to be recessed into it.

Apologies if StackOverflow isn't the right place for this - would be happy to move it onto a design forum if that is more appropriate.

Comment: What's abot this: http://jsfiddle.net/rrGab/13/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a recessed 'letterpress' effect you need two different colored borders, one for the top, one for the bottom, instead of a solid border.  Please refer to this article [here](http://line25.com/tutorials/create-a-letterpress-effect-with-css-text-shadow).  This technique is using text-shadow to create the effect with text, but I think you might could use the philosophy behind it and apply it to border color.

I agree that the solid border doesn't really make it pop.  What if you again did a two-toned border, but use the 'middle color' that your gradient produces up top, and then your bottom border could be ever so slightly darker than the bottom of your gradient?